# We are using redhat linux ver5.4.I kept printing job and how to stop it

Tags: linux

We are using redhat linux ver5.4.I kept printing job and how to stop it.The job was given from another remote system.I am unable to stop it. I have given cancel -a 4 times , but it was not stopped.

Comment: Using.. CUPS? How did you attempt to cancel it?

Answer (score 0):

RHEL uses CUPS, you should be able to navigate to `localhost:631` (the control page for local CUPS), go to the Jobs tab and kill it from there. If it isn't yours, you'll most probably get asked the local root password.